# Uncaught weird error in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Alright so this is the first time I see this problem while using Google Maps.

I have 2 simple files (html & JS) and it seems that one of them is causing these errors

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="map.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="test">
            <iframe id="map" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;spn=56.506174,79.013672&amp;t=m&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Java script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();

    function initialize() {
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
           myOptions);
    }
});
```

Error

> map.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function)
>   @ map.js:1 util.js:138 XHR finished loading: GET
>   "https://www.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i4!2i1!3i5!1m4!1m3!1i4!2i1!3i6!…ty_class!2s0!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e3!12m1!5b1&token=114164".SF
>   @ util.js:138_.TF @ util.js:138(anonymous function) @
>   onion.js:9XU.load @ onion.js:71$U @ onion.js:15YU.l @ onion.js:71
>   util.js:138 XHR finished loading: GET
>   "https://www.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i4!2i4!3i7!1m4!1m3!1i4!2i5!3i6!…ity_class!2s0!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e3!12m1!5b1&token=15750".

All I am trying to do is quite simple, I am trying to disable google maps options.

Comment: You're trying to use JQuery when evidently, it's not loaded.

Comment: Do you have jQuery inlcuded?

Comment: seem like it requires `Jquery`

Comment: a quick web search of `$ is not defined` should have turned up tons of results. Now we have to ask you a whole bunch of questions because you haven't even shown script tags in the html

Comment: Sorry I deleted it while posting, there is the link for JS, Ill edit the main post in a second

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jQuery linked in your HTML? The `$` var is looking for active jQuery to execute your `initialize()` function.

Comment: this isn't an answer .. use comment blocks to ask for clarification. It's not hard to get the 50 rep points needed to be able to use them

Comment: Yeah I have the Jquery linked, I accidentaly removed that part on code while I was posting but yep, I have it.